# How to transfer Facebook Albums across accounts?

Tags: facebook, merge, facebook-comments, account, data-transfer

Is there a way to transfer existing photo albums from one account to another, as is? (with the comments and likes). I currently have an account with 25 albums and would like to transfer those onto another account please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to transfer photos to another account using the API. The endpoint doesn't exist.